# How can I send int array from ajax to c# mvc?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, arrays, jquery, asp.net-ajax

How can I send int array from $.ajax to c# mvc?

Comment: I tried 3-4 examples I can't run it. What can be a reason?

Comment: [Ajax] public bool example(int[] ints)

Comment: please give more detail of what you have tried and what result you are seeing, including code.

Comment: I want to check all examples, but most of them send null to c# method.

Comment: I think @Darin Dimitrov has given the [appropriate answer here for this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8871602/2014745)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
          url: <Url of the action>,
          type: "POST",
          data: JSON.stringify([1,2,3]),
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

and in the action.

```
public ActionResult ReceiveIntArray(int[] ints)
{
   ...
}
```

mvc should parse the json automatically.

check out [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525053/passing-array-from-jquery-to-mvc-net-controller-giving-null-result-on-controller)

Comment: Doesn't work from my code... can't catch the reason. When I enter the method parameter is null.

Comment: sorry you would have to use JSON.stringify([1,2,3]) i have edited the answer

Comment: @Daniel it works for me too but, i have one question. why didn't matter what array name is ("ints")? Normally if  data: { BasvuruId: BasvuruId}, in js , Variable name must be same (BasvuruId) in action.

Comment: dataType:"json" is often overlooked... at least, by me.

Answer (score 3):

Try solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489461/pass-array-to-mvc-action-via-ajax):

> Set the `traditional` property to true before making the get call. i.e.:
>
> ```
> jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true
>
> $.get('/controller/MyAction', 
>     { vals: arrayOfValues }, 
>     function (data) {
>       ...
>     }
> ```

Comment: Code doesn't send values. Link is nice.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to send a delimited (commas, possibly) string list of the ints as an argument on a GET request, then use `Sting.Split()` to parse them on your C# MVC receiver.

So, for example
`$.get("/path-to/receiver/", { myArray: myArray.toString() } );`

Then, on the server, use

`string[] stringArray = Request.QueryString["myArray"].ToString().Split(',')`

to extract the values to a string array, then `Int32.TryParse` to finally get an array of ints.

[jQuery GET Syntax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)
[JS Array toString() syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp)

Comment: Doesn't send values. There is nothing to parse.

Comment: This is just an example - you would need to replace "myArray" etc with your own values.
The request url should be something like /path-to/receiver/?myArray=your,array,contents

Answer (score 2):

The way I'm doing it is with a simple `input:hidden` element

```
<input type="hidden" name="elements" value='@String.Join(",", ViewBag.MyArray)' />
```

And in the JavaScript code I'm passing it as a string:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: '/Controller/Method',
   data:
      {
          recipients: $("input[name=elements]").val()
      },
      traditional: true,
      success: updateSelected
});
```

And finally I just `Split` the elements like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Method(string elements)
{
    IList<long> selected = elements.Split<long>(',');
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

```
var Array = [10, 20, 30];

$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    datatype: "Json",
    url: <Url of the action>,
    data: JSON.stringify(Array),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

});
```