# What are the best ways to send arrays from js (jQuery) to sql sproc? Array transmitting between layers

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

**Array transmitting between layers.**

What are the best ways to send arrays from js (jQuery) to sql sproc?
Could you share your ideas?

This generalizes my previous questions:

1. Js to MVC controller.

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109671/1145224
2. Best way to send arrays from MVC to SQL. (Is still open for discussion)
3. And this interesting SQL post for testing. What about [Table Valued Parameters]?

   http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that best way is to send array as [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

How to pass an array to SP from MVC (any c# code). In your case it is a `int[]` array, right?

```
public static DataTable ConvertIntArrayToDataTable(IEnumerable<int> array, bool AllowNull = false)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(int)) { AllowDBNull = AllowNull });
    foreach(var i in array)
      dt.Rows.Add(i));
    return dt;
}
```

You also have to implement [User Defined Table Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526.aspx)

```
CREATE TYPE IntArray AS TABLE
(
  Value int not null
)
```

Create procedure which accepts this parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProc
  @DataArray IntArray READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT Value FROM @DataArray
END
```

and finally call the proc with approptiate parameter:

```
void CallProc(int[] array)
{
// assuming there is exisis already created connection and command named sqlCommand

  sqlCommand.CommandText = "YourProc";
  sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
  sqlCommand.AddWithValue("@DataArray", ConvertIntArrayToDataTable(array));
  sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: wow, that is perfect! clear and understandable. thank you so much!